# How to query effectively in Oracle SQL before inserting any data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

My scenario is like I have thousands of row in a table. And the table has 8 columns. I would like to check whether the exact same row exists in the table. My requirement I shouldn't insert the same row in the table twice. Obviously, to do so I have to compare every row before any new insertion. I don't have much SQL expertise, so I don't know what is the best way to so that I can gain maximum efficiency. Please advice me.

Comment: And what does SQL Server do here since you're asking about Oracle?

Comment: How should you handle the case where the "exact same row" doesn't exist, but the key does (i.e. inserting the row would violate a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple option is to create unique index that contains all those columns, e.g.

```
create unique index ui1_your_table on your_table (col1, col2,..., col8);
```

Database would take care about the rest.

Comment: I would prefer a unique constraint, even though it will be enforced by the same index. A constraint declares a rule about the data.